# iOS Quiz App, Jumble Multiple Choice But Remember Correct Answer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

I am following a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich that involves creating a quiz that can be used on an Apple TV to display the question, and the devices to answer.  In this, little time is spent on the logic of answering the questions.  The questions are stored in a plist file, where the first possible answer is always the correct one.  In code, it is shown as:

```
- (void)startQuestion
{
  // 1
  int questionIndex = arc4random_uniform((int)[self.questions count]);
  NSMutableArray *questionArray = [self.questions[questionIndex] mutableCopy];
  [self.questions removeObjectAtIndex:questionIndex];

  // 2
  NSString *question = questionArray[0];
  [questionArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

  // 3
  NSMutableArray *answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[questionArray count]];
  self.currentQuestionAnswer = -1;
  self.currentQuestionAnswersReceived = 0;

  while ([questionArray count] > 0)
  {
    // 4
    int answerIndex = arc4random_uniform((int)[questionArray count]);
    if (answerIndex == 0 && self.currentQuestionAnswer == -1)
    {
      self.currentQuestionAnswer = [answers count];
    }
    [answers addObject:questionArray[answerIndex]];
    [questionArray removeObjectAtIndex:answerIndex];
  }

  // 5
  [self sendToAllPeers:[kCommandQuestion stringByAppendingString:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[answers count]]]];
  [self.scene startQuestionWithAnswerCount:[answers count]];
  [self.mirroredScene startQuestion:question withAnswers:answers];
}
```

When the app is ran at the end of the tutorial, it always makes 'A' the correct answer.  Is there some way to tell the app that the first item under each question in the plist is the correct one, but have it randomize between ABCD so that each time the app is ran the answers are a different choice?

Comment: You could simply randomize the order and put the results in an array.  If the value of the array for the index(answer) provided by the player is the correct item then you can return true.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing any of that.  That's the reason I was looking to a tutorial, to help guide me along the way, not leave out the major piece to it.@jbarker2160